# Is there a max blocking time on BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

In the producer-consumer problem, I would like to use the `LinkedBlockingQueue` as the shared buffer.

Producer thread puts an element on the queue using the `put()` method and the Consumer thread consumes the element on the queue using the `take()` method.

My question is: say if the queue is empty and the consumer thread calls the `take()` method, I am aware that the thread is blocked until the producer puts an element on the queue. But is there something like a maximum block duration? Can I safely assume that the consumer thread will be blocked until the `put()` call?

I have heard people saying that there is nothing like block for ever. Is it true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't a timeout for the wait in the `take()` method. And the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take()) does not mention any timeout:

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary **until an element becomes available**.

The [`poll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#poll(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method, on the other hand, can take a timeout as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the implementation of LinkedBlockingQueue take() method
It awaits on notEmpty condition in a loop which will exit only if count becomes non-zero.

So YES, it will wait forever until the condition is satisfied, which means someone puts an element there.